# How to identify UIWebView as Safari

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Hi my UIWebView is identifying as Mozzila/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_2 like Mac OS X), and Safari is identifying as Safari iOS6. And the webpage that I want load with UIWebView only support Safari... It there some way to change it programmatically? I used https://browsercheck.qualys.com/ to check the browser.. Thank you for any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the default userAgent of the web browser:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Apple-iPhone/501.347", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

[UserAgent list website](http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings)